# Does Amnesty International maintain a list of prisoners of conscience?

Tags: human-rights

Has [Amnesty International](http://www.amnesty.org) ever maintained a list of people they officially designate as "prisoners of conscience" ?
If yes, where can this list be found?

*Context: I have recently found this Wikipedia category, which seems to imply there is such a designation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Amnesty_International_prisoners_of_conscience*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can look on the Amnesty International web site, I found a description page there on [Prisoners of Conscience](http://www.amnestyusa.org/our-work/issues/prisoners-and-people-at-risk/prisoners-of-conscience) that links to individuals.  As to individual lists you can across one at Wikipedia but I also found at least one on their site for [Cuba](http://www.amnesty.org/en/news-and-updates/news/cuba-list-prisoners-of-conscience) that lists many people.  You can probably find others, though I didn't do an indepth look on the site.

As to a full list, this news story from [The Nation](http://www.nationmultimedia.com/2011/05/26/national/Amnesty-wont-reveal-prisoners-of-conscience-30156244.html) notes that

> There is more than one prisoner of conscience in Thailand, although the number of those detained under lese majeste law and their names known to Amnesty International (AI) is "not for public consumption", said Benjamin Zawacki, AI's researcher for Thailand and Burma.

I did not see a similar general note, so you can probably take this as more focusing on Thailand and Burma, where I could see such a public list would endanger those on it.

Considering the list is in flux, and changing all the time, it'd be under constant revision especially since their definition of prisoner of conscience is both sort of flexible and not comprehensive since Amnesty International doesn't take all cases under consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the Cuba list, it is actually the kind of list I am looking for. But The first page you mentioned is just a definition, it does not link to individuals, right?

Comment: No, you can find lists on their site if you really look but they don't make it easy.  Mostly they call of specific individuals to give exposure to their cases.